# Where is the "Last Mobile Install Reported" field?

Tags: facebook

The [facebook Mobile App Install Ads Tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/) says:

> [...] go to the app summary page and there's a field "Last Mobile
>   Install Reported" that provides times stamp on the last time your app
>   reported an install.

I cannot find that field on my app summary page. That's assuming the app summary page is the one I can reach by clicking on "Apps" in the header bar of the facebook developers portal.

Where can I find that field? Is it optional, maybe?

**EDIT / Answer:**

It only appears after at least one install has been published by the app.

Comment: How long did it take for the app summary page to show the last mobile install after the app successfully made the `publishInstall` API call?

Comment: It was almost instantaneously. Certainly not more than a few minutes.

Comment: Did you have to install your app from Google Play for it to count? My app is in Google Play, but the Facebook integration changes have not yet been released; and I'm testing the unreleased version and not seeing the update on the app summary page.

Comment: Yes, for me it only worked for the released version. With the dev version in the emulator it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your app correctly configured as a native mobile app and using the newest version of the SDK?

For me the page loads fine and includes that information, it's the 
`https://developers.facebook.com/apps/<APP ID>` page, and the field is in the top part, along with the app description, support email address, etc:

[image]

Comment: That very field is missing from my page. I've set my app up as a native mobile app (selected the appropriate radio button). I'll try setting up a new app just to see if it will appear there. At least now I know what to look for.

Comment: Radio button? if you're referring to the 'Native/Desktop or Web' option for App Type in Advanced settings that does something else - it's the basic settings page where you enter your iOS app store and Google Play Store details, app classnames, etc, which determines if your app supports native mobile platforms

Comment: Yes, that's the one I'm referring to. But I also filled in the settings you described - both for iOS and Android.